# Bootstrap 4 Custom Styling CSS For Accordion Cards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have now been going at this for too long and would really like some help in getting this Bootstrap 4 accordion customised.

I would like the Background of the cards & Links transparent, the font Size changed, the font color changed and no underline. I have hooked every ID & Class possible using default and special classes, with !important and have had no luck. The Bootstrap 4 documentation only gives inline styles that are limited in color.

```css
.testing {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.special-card {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.special-card a {
  color: grey !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.special-card a:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header testing">
      <h6 class="card-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Title</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="card-block special-card">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 1</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 2</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit of adding the bootstrap source... but the link you added is for the 3.3.7 distribution, this is in accordance to Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi try below code i have added background color to body you can change it if needed

html

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="card text-center testing">
    <div class="card-header ">
      <h6 class="card-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Title</a>
      </h6>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="card-block special-card">
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 1</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 2</a>
        <a href="" class="list-group-item">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body
{
  background-color: #212121;
}



.testing{
  background-color: transparent;
}
.testing .card-header
{
  background-color: transparent;
}
.testing .card-title a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:20px;
  color:grey;
}

.special-card {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.special-card
{
  background-color: transparent;
}

.special-card a {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 15px;
   background-color: transparent;
}

.special-card a:hover {
  color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

no need of using !important flag..

hope this helps
[Here is a link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/KqVaMZ?editors=1100)